# Japanese characters are not displayed in IE6

Tags: utf-8, internationalization, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to display the japanese characters in my page. The page is working in all browsers except IE6. I noticed some sites http://translation.babylon.com/english/to-japanese/ display japanese characters as boxes. As i said earlier the page is working in all browsers except IE6.

The header i am using in the page is
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
and UTF-8 encoding

Could you please help to find out what is the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the font used does not have such glyphs? FWIW: http://www.jp41.com/internet-explorer/japanese/

Answer (score 0):

Usually content developer has to write right meta-tag for correct character decoding. Like this.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If there is no meta tag on the content, the browser has to decode the page by own auto decoding method. But auto decoding is not perfect. Sometime it works, sometime it doesn't work.